# How to use R window function for trimesters of short time series?

Tags: r, function, window

I have this short time-series

```
Semester    E
2015-01 828
2015-05 277
2015-08 2105
2016-01 1926
2016-05 619
2016-08 2389
2017-01 2522
2017-05 598
2017-08 2541
2018-01 2200
2018-05 644
2018-08 2541
2019-01 2031
```

I would like to transform it to this using window function in R up to 2018 (leave out 2019)

The final table is this:

```
          1 2   3
2015    828 277 2105
2016    1926    619 2389
2017    2522    598 2541
2018    2200    644 2541
```

How can I do that using window function?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to extract the 'year' and then `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Year = year(dmy(Term))) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    select(-Term) %>% 
    spread(rn, E)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Year [5]
#   Year   `1`   `2`   `3`
#  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#1  2015   828   277  2105
#2  2016  1926   619  2389
#3  2017  2522   598  2541
#4  2018  2200   644  2541
#5  2019  2301    NA    NA
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
Year <- format(as.Date(df1$Term, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y")
s1 <- ave(seq_along(Year), Year, FUN = seq_along)
xtabs(df1$E ~ Year + s1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Term = c("1/1/2015", "5/1/2015", "8/1/2015", 
 "1/1/2016", "5/1/2016", "8/1/2016", "1/1/2017", "5/1/2017", "8/1/2017", 
 "1/1/2018", "5/1/2018", "8/1/2018", "1/1/2019"), E = c(828L, 
 277L, 2105L, 1926L, 619L, 2389L, 2522L, 598L, 2541L, 2200L, 644L, 
 2541L, 2301L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I was looking for something like that:Y <- window(E, start=c(2015, 1), end=c(2018, 3))

Comment: @user22478  I noticed that you removed the data from the post and included a pic.  I would revert it back to the earlier version

Comment: This is the error I got when I run your code: > View(df1)
> View(East)
> df1 %>% 
+   group_by(Year = year(dmy(Term))) %>%
+   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
+   select(-Term) %>% 
+   spread(rn, E)
Error in select(., -Term) : unused argument (-Term)

Comment: @user22478  I can't reproduce the error with the `data` I showed in the post

Comment: @user22478  I forgot to specify `library(tidyr)`  can you load it and try

Comment: Interesting... i still got the error: Error in select(., -Term) : unused argument (-Term)  I dunno thank you though

Comment: @user22478  Is the error from the same data in my post?

Comment: @user22478  I used `packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.8.0.1’
> packageVersion("tidyr")
[1] ‘0.8.3’`

Comment: @user22478  If it an issue with the package version, then the second option should work fine as it is `base R`

Comment: yes the base works - will update r and rstudio thank you!